# Element of Grothendieck group is eigenvector of operator

Tags: representation-theory

Let $K_\mathbb{C}(G)$ be the Grothendieck group (over $\mathbb{C}$) of finite dimensional representations of a finite group $G$. Associated with any such representation $V$, there is a linear operator$$t_V: K_\mathbb{C}(G) \to K_\mathbb{C}(G)$$given by the assignment$$[M] \mapsto t_V([M]) := [V \otimes M].$$How do I see that the element $[\mathbb{C}G] \in K_\mathbb{C}(G)$, the class of the regular representation of $G$, is an eigenvector of the operator $t_V$, for any $G$-representation $V$?

Comment: Use the fact that associating to a representation its character defines an isomorphism of $K(G)\otimes \mathbb{C}$ with the ring of central functions on $G$. The question would be more appropriate on MSE.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is over $\mathbb{C}$, a representation is uniquely determined by its character. Thus, it suffices to show that the character of $V\otimes \mathbb{C}G$ is a multiple of the character of $\mathbb{C}G$.
But this is trivial, since the character of $\mathbb{C}G$ just has value $|G|$ at the identity and $0$ elsewhere, so the character of $V\otimes \mathbb{C}G$ is just the dimension of $V$ times the character of $\mathbb{C}G$.